asp.net with vue js FsLightbox lybrary Access to XMLHttpRequest origin has been blocked by CORS policy
asp.net with vue js FsLightbox lybrary Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:44347/CarImages/3e0da2fa7fd0417ea2e2f4678229e264Logo.png' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. error
when use FsLightbox library show this error , im use this images path in another slider its run good
and im use another images from internet to FsLightbox also run good
this problem just appear when use my images paths with FsLightbox !!??
// this is policy code from program.cs 
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(
        builder =>
        {
            //you can configure your custom policy
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                                .AllowAnyHeader()
                                .AllowAnyMethod();
        });
});
var app = builder.Build();
// Apply CORS policy
app.UseCors();

/////////////////////
// this in vue js FsLightbox like documntation
<FsLightbox :toggler="toggler" :sources="vehicleImages" />


This question is similar to: Dotnet Core 3.1 cors issue when serving static image files. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
